# Base Case for Real Spectral Thm. Proof in Axler `s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, proof-explanation

Specifically, prove that if $T\in\mathcal{L}(V)$ is self-adjoint, then $V$ has an orthonormal basis consisting of eigenvectors of $T$.

Axler inducts on $n=$dim($V)$ starting with Base Case $n=1.$ He offers no reasoning for the base case, which is seemingly fine as it is easy to see \begin{alignat*}{2}V\text{ is 1-dim. with basis }\{v\}\;\;\;&\implies\;\;\;&&T(v)=\lambda v\text{ (for some }\lambda\in\mathbb{R})\\&\implies &&T\text{ has a basis of eigenvectors, namely }\{v\}\end{alignat*}which is easily made into an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors of $T$; e.g. letting $e=||v||^{-1}\cdot v,$ we get $||e||=1$ and $T(e)=T(||v||^{-1}v)=||v||^{-1}\lambda v=\lambda||v||^{-1}v=\lambda e$.

Great. But where did we use $T$ is self-adjoint? Or better yet, where did we need that $T$ is self-adjoint?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Every linear map on a one-dimensional real vector space is self-adjoint (multiplication by scalars is self-adjoint).  I imagine the inductive step uses the assumption $T$ is self-adjoint more obviously since every dimension $>1$ has non-self-adjoint linear maps.

Comment: @BrianMoehring: Thank you for the comment, wasn't sure if I was missing something obvious. Guess not. Perhaps n=2 would've made a better Base Case, as T being self-adjoint in the n=1 case doesn't imply anything that wasn't already true.

Comment: @greycatbird Trivial base cases are ideal. Math is hard, don't make it harder than it needs to be :P You do need the self-adjointness for the induction step, so it's not like the hypothesis is redundant.

Comment: Note that you *do* need the hypothesis working over $\Bbb C$ to infer that the eigenvalue is real.

Comment: Thanks all for comments. @BrandonduPreez: How dull! Don`t you ever wonder why things work, instead of just accepting that they do? But yeah, the n=2 case isn`t trivial (although a little more fulfilling), so in the off chance anybody ever cares, I`ll attach it and close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We explicitly use the self-adjoint property in the $n=2$ case. See below.

Suppose dim$(V)=n=2$. Suppose $T$ is self-adjoint. By Thm. 7.27, $T$ has an eigenvalue $\lambda_1$. Let is corresponding eigenvector be $v_1$. Extend $v_1$ to basis $v_1,v_2$ of $V.$ Define $T(v_2)=av_1+bv_2$, where $a,b\in\mathbb{R}.$

Use Gram-Schmidt to create orthonormal basis consisting of $$e_1=\frac{v_1}{||v_1||}\;\text{ and }\;e_2=\frac{v_2-\langle v_2,e_1\rangle e_1}{||v_2-\langle v_2,e_1\rangle e_1||}.$$ It is easy to see $T(e_1)=\lambda_1e_1$. To see $e_2$ is an eigenvector, observe \begin{alignat*}{2}T(e_2)&=\frac{T(v_2)-\langle v_2,e_1\rangle T(e_1)}{||v_2-\langle v_2,e_1\rangle e_1||} \qquad&&\,\\&=\frac{T(v_2)-\lambda_1\langle v_2,e_1\rangle e_1}{||v_2-\langle v_2,e_1\rangle e_1||} &&\,\\&=\frac{T(v_2)-\langle v_2, \lambda_1e_1\rangle e_1}{||v_2-\langle v_2,e_1\rangle e_1||} &&(\text{since $\lambda_1\in\mathbb{R}$})\\&=\frac{T(v_2)-\langle v_2, T(e_1)\rangle e_1}{||v_2-\langle v_2,e_1\rangle e_1||} &&(\text{def. of $T(e_1)$)}\\&=\frac{T(v_2)-\langle T(v_2), e_1\rangle e_1}{||v_2-\langle v_2,e_1\rangle e_1||} &&(\text{since $T$ is self-adjoint})\\&=\frac{av_1+bv_2-\langle av_1+bv_2, e_1\rangle e_1}{||v_2-\langle v_2,e_1\rangle e_1||} &&\,\\&=\frac{bv_2-b\langle v_2, e_1\rangle e_1}{||v_2-\langle v_2,e_1\rangle e_1||}+\frac{av_1-\langle av_1,e_1\rangle e_1}{||v_2-\langle v_2,e_1\rangle e_1||} &&\,\\&=\frac{bv_2-b\langle v_2, e_1\rangle e_1}{||v_2-\langle v_2,e_1\rangle e_1||}+\frac{av_1-a\langle v_1,e_1\rangle \cdot\frac{v_1}{||v_1||}}{||v_2-\langle v_2,e_1\rangle e_1||} &&\,\\&=\frac{bv_2-b\langle v_2, e_1\rangle e_1}{||v_2-\langle v_2,e_1\rangle e_1||}+\frac{av_1-a\langle \frac{v_1}{||v_1||},e_1\rangle v_1}{||v_2-\langle v_2,e_1\rangle e_1||} &&\,\\&=\frac{bv_2-b\langle v_2, e_1\rangle e_1}{||v_2-\langle v_2,e_1\rangle e_1||}+\frac{av_1-a\langle e_1,e_1\rangle v_1}{||v_2-\langle v_2,e_1\rangle e_1||} &&\,\\&=\frac{bv_2-b\langle v_2, e_1\rangle e_1}{||v_2-\langle v_2,e_1\rangle e_1||}+\frac{av_1-av_1}{||v_2-\langle v_2,e_1\rangle e_1||} &&\,\\&=b\frac{v_2-\langle v_2, e_1\rangle e_1}{||v_2-\langle v_2,e_1\rangle e_1||}+0\\&=be_2.\end{alignat*} This completes the case where $n=2.$